# How do I get the name of a right clicked item in a folder in windows using C++

Tags: windows, winapi, explorer, windows-shell

I want to use C++  Win32 API to get the name of a right clicked item in a folder

For this :
[image]

I want to get "wordpad.exe"

Comment: [Monitoring Internet Explorer and Explorer windows - Part 2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130613-00/?p=4093), [Monitoring Internet Explorer and Explorer windows, part 3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130614-00/?p=4083) -- [ShellFolderView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shellfolderview) -- [SHChangeNotify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shchangenotify)

Comment: You can get the selected item(s) for a given Explorer view (window) https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040720-00/?p=38393 but there can be more than one (you could check which one is on front) and you can't easily relate all that with the context menu open (beyond the fact you can detect there's currently a top level window which is a menu, in explorer.exe process, so probably not in same process as you). Also note multiple items can be selected. Also there are lots of possible race conditions between your code and what the user does (click somewhere else, close menu, etc.)

Comment: A context menu extension could do this, even if it doesn't add anything to the menu you still get told which items are selected.